# How to increment property in loop Vue 2?

Tags: for-loop, vuejs2

Template : have function in curly braces setSr() for increment previous property

```
<ul v-for="i in 5" :key="i">
    <li>{{setSr()}} {{i}} {{ preivous  }} </li>
  </ul>
```

data property previous initial 1

```
 data(){
        return{
               preivous:1,
              }
       }
```

Method

```
methods:{
        setSr(){
                 this.preivous =(this.preivous+1); 
            }
     }
```

Output

`1 2022 2 2023  3 2024  4 2025  5 2026`

Expected output next want increment previous by condition wise

1 0
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4

Answer (score 0):

Avoid on-the-fly stuff like this in the template loop and do stuff like this and restructure what's needed before you output.

For example, make a range method to compute your range, if your use it ever again, abstract it into a mixin etc, and then use a computed value to call it, setting a default in data.

```js
const utilsMixin = {
  methods: {
    range(start, end, step) {
      // ascii a-z
      if (typeof start === 'string' && typeof end === 'string') {
        const result = []
        for (let idx = start.charCodeAt(0), e = end.charCodeAt(0); idx <= e; ++idx) {
          result.push(String.fromCharCode(idx))
        }
        return result
      }
      // number or date
      const range = []
      typeof step === 'undefined' && (step = 1)
      if (end < start) {
        step = -step
      }
      while (step > 0 ? end >= start : end <= start) {
        range.push(start)
        start += step
      }
      return range
    }
  }
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mixins: [
    utilsMixin
  ],
  data: () => ({
    limit: 5
  }),
  computed: {
    years() {
      return this.range(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getFullYear() + this.limit)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(year, i) in years" :key="i">{{i}} {{ year }} </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```